# Improving drawing object in OpenGL (currently super slow)

Tags: algorithm, opengl

**intro:**

I have a file that resembles .obj format which long story short means:

- I have an array filled with coordinates of potential vertices
- An array filled with triplets of indices (which correspond to the coordinate array)
- The indices define a triangle, so the entire array will define the shape

**My method:**

- create an array of 9 floats for each face, containing the coordinates of each vertex
- for each face, I run through this (simplified) code:

  ```
  glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, array_size, array, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
  ```

The issue is that when I get to big files with a lot of faces it is really slow... for example a 5000 face shape is taking around 5 seconds per frame.

I am considering converting the file into a large mesh and then drawing it but I don't know how to approach such a problem and I also don't know if that will fix my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you allocate a buffer for each face, you fill it and then you draw it. Each frame.

As the vertices of your shapes are static, the right way to do this would be to allocate your buffers during the loading of your game, fill them, and only perform the binding and drawing operations at each frame.

Even better, you could allocate one large buffer containing all your vertices data concatenated, and use indexed drawing (have a look at `glDrawElements`), which would avoid to perform the binding operation at each frame, again doing it only once.

Answer (score 4):

> for each face, I run through this (simplified) code

This is the problem, overhead of interfacing with GPU is huge compared to actual drawing time of a single triangle. Draw the entire mesh in a single call.